# QGIS-Merging raster to get altitude lines

Tags: qgis, raster

I am still a beginner when it comes to the functions in QGIS. However, I would like to create my own topography map and my research has shown that this is easy to do using raster data. I have already downloaded the raster files from the Earthdata website and would first like to create the contour lines from them. I was advised to merge the rasters beforehand so that I get a coherent image. I have done this both by "merging" and by using a "virtual raster". With both versions, I get the same, unsatisfactory result that I can hardly create any contour lines in the north of the country (see pic 1)[image: Only a few contour lines are visible here]. This is different with the individual images or less merged images(see pic 2)[image: Many contour lines have been created here]. The two results are obtained even though the input parameters are the same, and I dont know why. However, I would probably have to touch up the contour lines individually at the edges of the individual grids, which would be an enormous effort with 72 images for the country, which is why, in my opinion, I need the merged one.
I know that I can select the intervals of the different altitude lines, but I cannot create the same altitude lines in the merged grid.
The range of individual elevation meters per raster automatically and correctly adjusts to the total difference of all rasters.
I don't quite understand what the problem is and how I can work around it.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What actually IS unsatisfactory about the result with merged rasters vs independent rasters? Add screenshots of concrete examples to clearly show your issue. And your expected outcome.

Comment: I tried to visualize my problem. For my topological map I need the altitude lines for the whole of Germany, unfortunately the merged grid produces far too few (especially in the northern area). The same settings are used as for the individual images.

Comment: What format are you writing to? If it is Shapefile, bear in mind they have a 2Gb limit and the output of the contours tool looks very heavy. Or it could be that your system does not have enough memory to process the entire mosaicked raster.

Comment: I tried it in a shape file, but it was indeed canceled after 2Gb and I was missing the south of Germany, but the north looked good. 
In the photos the files are written as gpkg files.
Do you have any idea how I can work around this?